# What's the appropriate return type for a Typescript function returning an AsyncFunction?

Tags: typescript, async-await

This code should work OK...

```
let AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;

export function createJsFunction(event: string, body: string[]): any {
  return new AsyncFunction(body.join("\n") + "\n//# sourceURL=" + event);
}
```

.. but the "any" return value of `createJsFunction` offends me. What's the appropriate type to return?

If I'm using the regular `Function` type, it's obviously just `Function`... but using `AsyncFunction` I get `Cannot find name 'AsyncFunction'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can narrow the type of `AsyncFunction` a little. The built-in typings say it's `any`, but we know it's really a `FunctionConstructor`.

```
let AsyncFunction: FunctionConstructor = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function () {}).constructor;
```

Now we can use it just as we would use the standard `Function` constructor.

```
const createJsFunction = new AsyncFunction('event', 'body', `
  await body.join('\\n') + '\\n//# sourceURL=' + event
`);
```

(Note the double backslash inside the template string.)

This works, but the inferred type for `createJsFunction` is just `Function`. That's because there is no way for the type system to tell what the result is going to be at compile-time.

If we know what the actual signature will be, we can tell TypeScript about it by using a type assertion (here: `as (event: string, body: string[]) => Promise<string>`):

```
const createJsFunction = new AsyncFunction('event', 'body', `
  body.join('\\n') + '\\n//# sourceURL=' + event
`) as (event: string, body: string[]) => Promise<string>;
```

As you mentioned in your comment, the advantage of using the `AsyncFunction` constructor is that you can `await` inside the function you are constructing.

```
const createJsFunction = new AsyncFunction('event', 'body', `
  await body.join('\\n') + '\\n//# sourceURL=' + event
`) as (event: string, body: string[]) => Promise<void>;
```

Comment: Yes createJsFunction *is* a regular function that should return an async function. but are you sure about functions returning promise automatically being `async`?? Surely you can't use `await` in a function that isn't explicitly async?

Comment: See JSBin here https://jsbin.com/perehasise/1/edit?js,console based on MDN here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction (I'm aware I've stepped back to Javascript to try and understand this!) Replaced the Function() call with AsyncFunction() and it works.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. By _assumed to be an async function automatically_ I meant they are all the same on the type level. In other words, all these conform to the same type signature: type (`AsyncFunction<T = any> = (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>`): `const foo: AsyncFunction = () => Promise.resolve(0)`, `const bar: AsyncFunction = async () => 0`, `const baz: AsyncFunction = async function () { return 0; }`. I didn't know you wanted to `await` inside your function body — I will alter my answer so nobody gets confused in the future.

Comment: Slightly late to get back, but here's what I needed. `export function createJsFunction(event: string, body: string[]): Function {
  return new AsyncFunction(body.join("\n") + "\n//# sourceURL=" + event);
}`. Your answers pointed me in the right direction. The return type is Function rather than AsyncFunction but appears to work regardless. Worth noting that Typescript needs Target=ES2017 or later to generate an AsyncFunction this way.

Comment: Worth nothing indeed! The return type is `Function` because there is no type called `AsyncFunction`. We only have a variable called `AsyncFunction` of type `Function`. Its constructor, which is what you are using, is also defined to return `Function`. That's why type assertions are sometimes useful.